# Awk output as input parameter in pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm new to shell scripting and trying to figure out why my code won't work. I am trying to use the output from an awk statement as an input parameter in a pipe. I think this is pretty simple so hopefully someone can help me out!

I am starting with a very simple file called `sample.bed` that looks like this:

```
chr1 35031657 35037706
chr1 67544575 67550598
chr1 71979382 71985425
chr1 81404889 81410942
chr1 84518073 84524089
chr1 86214203 86220231
```

I have two variables, $P and $G, where $P is the path to the sample.bed file and $G is just set to `"hg38"`.

The first thing I do is check the number of columns in the file. Since it is 3, and since $G is set to `"hg38"`, the variable named `$twobit` is set.

```
num_col=$(cat $P | awk '{print NF; exit}')

if [ $num_col==3 ]
then
echo "3 column bed file, no directional considerations for sequences"
    if (( $G=="hg38" ))
    then
        twobit="https://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.2bit"
    fi
fi
```

So far so good.

twoBitToFa is a tool that accepts 4-column files, the 4th column being a unique identifier than is a combination of the first 3 columns. I attempt to create that necessary 4th column with `awk '{print $0" "$1":"$2"-"$3}' $P`, which shows up in my terminal correctly:

```
chr1 35031657 35037706 chr1:35031657-35037706
chr1 67544575 67550598 chr1:67544575-67550598
chr1 71979382 71985425 chr1:71979382-71985425
chr1 81404889 81410942 chr1:81404889-81410942
chr1 84518073 84524089 chr1:84518073-84524089
chr1 86214203 86220231 chr1:86214203-86220231
```

And here's where I am stuck. I want to use this printed output as input for the next step that uses the twoBitToFa tool. This tool needs the 4-column file as input and the $twobit URL to output a .fa file.

I have tried to save the awk output to a variable, but when I do that I lose the data table structure and everything prints on one line, like so:

```
new_dat=$(awk '{print $0" "$1":"$2"-"$3}' $P)
echo $new_dat

chr1 35031657 35037706 chr1:35031657-35037706 chr1 67544575 67550598 chr1:67544575-67550598 chr1 71979382 71985425 chr1:71979382-71985425 chr1 81404889 81410942 chr1:81404889-81410942 chr1 84518073 84524089 chr1:84518073-84524089 chr1 86214203 86220231 chr1:86214203-86220231
```

I tried using passing this new_dat variable on anyway, like so, but get an error that says "string option -bed must have a value"

```
twoBitToFa -bed $new_dat -udcDir=. $twobit stdout > $P.fa
```

I tried skipping saving the new variable and using the pipe operator to pass the data to twoBitToFa, which does *sort of* work, because it does create the .fa file, but it's trying to extract all of chr1, I guess because the sequence ranges aren't being passed properly.

```
awk '{print $0" "$1":"$2"-"$3}' $P | twoBitToFa -udcDir=. $twobit stdout > $P.fa
```

So, I think I have issues with printing and/or with how I am attempting to save my new_dat variable. Is "print" the wrong thing to be using with awk?

I don't want to write the 4-column file on my machine using  `>` , since this would create many unnecessary intermediate files down the line. Ideally, my whole script would look something like this:

```
num_col=$(cat $P | awk '{print NF; exit}')

if [ $num_col==3 ]
then
echo "3 column bed file, no directional considerations for sequences"
    if (( $G=="hg38" ))
    then
        twobit="https://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.2bit"
    fi
awk '{print $0" "$1":"$2"-"$3}' $P | twoBitToFa -??? -udcDir=. $twobit stdout > $P.fa
fi
```

Where the ??? is somehow the output from the awk statement. Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions!

Comment: `if [ $num_col==3 ]` should be `if [ $num_col = 3 ]`. The spaces around `=` are required.

Comment: You can't write `(( $G=="hg38" ))`. `(())` is for arithmetic expressions, and `hg38` is not a number.

Comment: Please paste your code into shellcheck.net and fix all the basic syntax errors.

Comment: Would be worth adding `twoBitToFa` is a utility related to the Genome project, to your question to help others understand what that utility is and where to look if they need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `-bed=stdin` seems to work:

```bash
p=./sample.bed

awk '{print $0, $1":"$2"-"$3}' "$p" |
twoBitToFa -bed=stdin -udcDir=. "$twobit" stdout > "${p%.bed}".fa
```